# WooCommere product_type property is returning simple when it's the product is variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm struggling with a loop and a simple/variable product types in Woocommerce 3.1.2. All loops go through **`loop/add-to-cart.php`** which is custom in my theme (not made by me) and goes something like this:

```
global $product;

echo '<li class="cart_view">';
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
            sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
                esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                esc_attr( $product->id ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
                $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
                esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
        $product );
        echo '</li>';
```

Everything (IDs, href, etc.) is working (properly?) except for the `$product->product_type`, which is returning *simple* even when it's variable.

**Except for one product**, which returns variable. I just can't get why, as it has the same setup as the others.

Doing the single/variable condition in single product works ok.

I have tried already other methods such as `has_child()` and they also fail.

What is possibly going wrong here? Any ideas on where to start?

---

**EDIT:** `get_type()` instead of `product_type()` behaves the same way. `add_to_cart_text()` is also failing, so it might be something else.

Comment: have you tried $product->get_type() instead? [source of my guess](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13142)